# Vaadin 7: Uploading large files in background thread

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

In Vaadin 7 (or Vaadin 8, I suppose), how do we upload files in a background thread, using Vaadin `Upload` component?  The Vaadin documentation has examples of using the progress bar, but no examples of actually uploading in another thread.  In my case, it is locking the Vaadin session for my browser until the file is uploaded.  If I could do it in a background thread, I could get around the issue.

I set all the listeners in the `Upload` component, and I can do other things in the background just fine, I just don't even know where to start to do the actual upload in the background.  I even see an example online for processing the file in the background, I just don't see an example for uploading a file in the background.

My goal is to run it in another thread so the Vaadin session as a whole is not locked (thus enabling me to use other browser tabs for the same website, for instance).

Here are some logs where we potentially see locking DURRING the upload.  It is not perfect, but it is suggestive.

```
[2024-01-31 13:33:23 EST] INFO com.mobiwms.website.view.upload.CsvFilesComponent uploadStarted Starting upload of file [January1.0B.csv], session locked? true
[2024-01-31 13:33:23 EST] INFO com.mobiwms.website.view.upload.CsvFilesComponent receiveUpload Uploading file January1.0B.csv, mime type text/csv, session locked? true
[2024-01-31 13:33:23 EST] INFO com.mobiwms.website.view.upload.CsvFilesComponent updateProgress Progress of upload, read 4096 bytes, out of 345369, session locked? true
[2024-01-31 13:33:23 EST] INFO com.mobiwms.website.view.upload.CsvFilesComponent updateProgress Progress of upload, read 345369 bytes, out of 345369, session locked? true
[2024-01-31 13:33:23 EST] INFO com.mobiwms.website.view.upload.CsvFilesComponent uploadSucceeded Succeeded in uploading of file [January1.0B.csv], session locked? true
[2024-01-31 13:33:54 EST] INFO com.mobiwms.website.view.upload.CsvFilesComponent openFile Openning file [January1.0B.csv], session locked? true
[2024-01-31 13:33:54 EST] INFO com.mobiwms.website.view.upload.CsvFilesComponent uploadFinished Finished upload of file [January1.0B.csv], session locked? true
```

As you can see, `VaadinSession.getCurrent().hasLock()` returns true much of the way through the process.  I suppose these "upload" methods could be triggered during times where the session is locked, but the "opening file" log is before I start a thread to open the file locally.  I actually thought it would be false there, but it was true.  Granted, so far `hasLock` always returns true, but that could be only because I happen to be checking it at the wrong time.  If anyone thinks it would be helpful to find such a place, and can point me in such a place, I can add the corresponding log.

Comment: Would you post a code exaple where it does NOT do that? IIRC (and I'm pretty sure I do :-) ) the stream handling is done in a request that does not lock the session. And the main communication channel (that pretty much all other components use) can be used during the upload. The the UI is locked during the events fired by Upload though. If you are planning to consume the uploaded data in some service (instead of saving  files), the [UploadFileHandler](https://github.com/viritin/viritin/blob/master/viritin/src/main/java/org/vaadin/viritin/components/UploadFileHandler.java) might be handy.

Comment: This is basic Vaadin 7 Upload logic, nothing fancy.  I just save the file to disk.  I am rather certain the session is locked while it does the actual upload because I cannot do anything with the same website in another browser tab.  Once it finishes uploading, and starts processing things in a backend service (which does happen in another thread), I can do things in the other browser tab just fine.  I did see a brief session lock in the lower level code, but I just assumed it was too brief to cause a problem.  I will add that to my post.

Comment: Looks good to me, locked for events, but not while streaming actual data. https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/7.7/server/src/main/java/com/vaadin/server/communication/FileUploadHandler.java#L537

Comment: Good point, I missed that it was locking right around each of those places where I logged the "lock" state.  Does not answer why it seems to be locking at other times, but I cannot prove it is with 100% certainty.  I can only describe my experiences.